# Not able to update due date field in task

Tags: process-builder, opportunity, tasks, create-records

I'm having a process builder which creates a task whenever the stage is "Prospect". Now all is fine except due date field update. I'm setting "TODAY() + 7" in "Due Date Only" field in process builder. But this is not reflecting in the record.

[image]

Comment: what is being set on the record as the due date?

Comment: Empty Value !! @glls

Comment: what is the type of field `Due Date Only` ? are you sure you don't have other PBs that null out the value - check debug log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. This has worked for me.

```
DATETIMEVALUE(TODAY()) + 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Due date only is a sort of formula field, I believe. It takes the due datetime and pulls only the date. Populate the full due date (which is actually a datetime) and it should work.